# Ring of germs of holomorphic functions at $0\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

So I've been reading the book and they used a induction proof where they just state that for the base case the ring of germs of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ is Noetherian.  I looked at other book and they start at the trivial case $\mathbb{C}^0$, so they weren't very helpful.I was wondering why the above result is true if anyone could explain to me. Thanks.

Comment: Take an ideal $I$ and consider $N=\inf\{\textrm{order of the zero of } f \textrm{ at } 0\mid f\in I\}$. What do you conclude? Good luck!

Comment: I think I see. We can just take $z^N$ as a generator for I, correct?

Comment: you have the idea :)